# How to run software which requires the latest Intel modules

Tags: drivers, software-installation, 14.10, software-sources, canonical

I used [this utility](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8) to upgrade all of my Intel modules on my machine, but soon after learned that it was a really bad idea to upgrade these because of incompatibilities, and especially with Unity.

I understand that it is good to wait for Canonical to release the updates so that nothing bad happens when you apply them as they may come with other patches which fix the incompatibilities.

So really what my question is, if Canonical does not provide these latest module upgrades, how can I run this software which requires them? Or equally, how can I safely install them?

**Information Update:**

Specifically the modules that I need to upgrade are my graphics ones.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Comment: My apologies, but it's unclear (at least to me) what Intel modules you are speaking of as well as what software you need them to run properly. Please [edit] your question to clarify. This will help us help you! Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek: OK, I have edited my question to include that information.

Comment: @ElderGeek: If you wish for me to provide any more information please just ask and I will include it in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be a pain, but without knowing exactly which intel graphics drivers you feel are required or exactly which chess game you require them for I have no way of testing a solution.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Sorry, I don't in fact know which graphics drivers that I need, so I was hoping for a solution which would be something which could just do all the upgrading for me. And I don't know where I got the Chess game from, sorry if I am not being much help.

Comment: Your current module is `i915` ?

Comment: What command are you using to launch said unknown chess game and what errors do you experience?

Comment: @ElderGeek: Ok, I have fully updated my question to fully explain what I need. Sorry if the question has changed very much now, I was hoping to get this information without needing to include all the information. But then my original question started to even confuse myself, so I decided to change it! :D Sorry if I have been confusing or caused any confusion.

Comment: @ElderGeek: It is a jar, so I am just launching it with `java -jar <jar>`. And I am experiencing no errors, as that only launches a launcher which then launches the actual Chess game so I don't see any errors actually given by the Chess game itself. But the Chess game does note that there are problems with older Intel graphics modules, and I am finding that the board etc are flickering, and the graphics are just working very badly. This was not the case though when I had Windows and the latest modules, and this Chess game. So I am assuming that it is the modules.

Comment: Did you dig into the details and also install the supported Intel graphics stack? https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/2014q4-intel-graphics-stack-release

Comment: @ElderGeek: No, I did not, what are these and would they help to remove the  incompatibilities?

Comment: Well as it says on the download page that that's the graphics stack they are supporting with the driver you say you've downloaded I would take them at there word and expect it to work that way until I had proof to the contrary. If you are using an unsupported graphics stack now, It would seem logical to expect that to be the source of the incompatibilities. Granted I can't test this for you. But I recall having to do something similar (last year as I recall) to get some Intel drivers working on Ubuntu 12.04 for whatever that's worth.  <jar> is not a jar name.

Comment: @ElderGeek: Ok, I will attempt that and report on how it goes. Also, when I said `<jar>`, I meant for that to be replaced with the name of the jar, be it `Chess.jar` or something else.

Comment: @ElderGeek: On that graphics stack page there are many downloads, which one do I choose?

Comment: I used the whole stack as I recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to keep your video drivers updates is the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  These include Mesa, nVidia and Bumblebee.

*However,* as the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to [their page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions after reading their page, leave a comment below.
I like to honour the people that put all of their great work out there for us mere mortals, so this is a bit out of my control...

So feel free to comment below!

Comment: Intel also? o_O

Comment: Mesa, sorry...  Adapted!

Answer (score 2):

There's a community mantained installer for the latest `Intel` drivers at [01.org](https://01.org/):

1. Download the latest version of `Intel(R) Graphics Installer for Linux` from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads)
2. Open the `.deb` file to open the package into `Ubuntu Software Center`
3. Click on the "`Install`" button on the top-right corner
4. Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (or click on the `Unity Dash` icon on the `Unity Launcher`) and type "`Intel(R) Graphics Installer For Linux`"
5. Click on the program's icon and go through the walkthrough

Comment: This is the utility that I was told would be dangerous (I linked to it in my question as well).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Why would it be dangerous?

Comment: I don't know, ask Fabby, he's the one who said it...